# Templates with playa returning blank pages

Tags: playa, stash

I have a fully-functioning EE site (which I didn't build) but I am migrating over to a new server, and everything is operating as it should with the exception of pages that have playa code in it.  If I remove the playa code, the page works.

Playa 4.4.5 / EE 2.7.3 / PHP  5.3.2

Here is an example of code that works on the old server but not on the old:

```
{exp:stash:set_list
    name="related_insights"
    parse_tags="yes"
  }
  {exp:playa:children
     field="cf_hm_related_resources"
     status="open"
     disable="members"
    }
    {lv_md_related_insights}
  {/exp:playa:children}
{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

I've tried deleting cache. I've tried enabling debugging.  All I get is a blank page unless I remove this snippet of code.  Any ideas?  Any ideas on what I can do to get some insight into what's happening?

Comment: What if you remove only `{lv_md_related_insights}`?

Comment: Good call, Derek.  Adding that code back in and removing just that line seems to avoid the blank screen.  That line references a stash file that contains a bunch of stash variables.  Does that give you a clue of where the problem might be?

Comment: Yeah, on your way to finding what's up - add the contents of that snippet back line by line and see where the error occurs.

Comment: it seems that the mere presence of any stash variables causes the problem.   So just this:  {stash:related_entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:related_entry_id} and it fails.  I wish I had more information.

Answer (score 0):

White pages or blank pages in EE are typically caused by PHP hitting memory limits.

First step is to check your PHP error logs... if the error is logged there, it'll indicate the issue. If it's memory, the solution is to increase the memory to which PHP has access in the php.ini file.

Another place it look is in the system/index.php file. Enable debugging in the file so you can see the error... You may need to remove the conditional code around the error reporting all together to see it.

Information on this page in the help docs might help:
https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/troubleshooting/general/blank_pages.html

Comment: Thanks, Anna.  I've seen references to these steps (I would love to not be flying blind!), and I have done all of the things suggested.  I have turned debug on (though nothing appears), I am not getting any PHP errors.  It's possible that I am missing something, but so far it isn't obvious what that is.

Comment: Make sure you're logged in as super admin and check the front end page in the same browser to see the debug info.

Comment: Try adding error_reporting(E_ALL); at the very bottom of the /system/index.php file. If that doesn't work, download your /system/expressionengien/third_party/ directory and do a grep search for "error_reporting"... if you see it, comment it out one at a time and check to see if there error is visible.